# Cannot use sync_to_async decorator after raising asyncio.CancelledError

Tags: python-3.x, django, python-asyncio, asgi

```
import asyncio
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async


@sync_to_async
def sync_func():
    print("sync_func() was CALLED (good!)")


async def async_func():
    print("async_func() was CALLED (good!)")


async def test(excep_type: type = asyncio.CancelledError):
    print(f"\nException Type: {excep_type}")
    try:
        raise excep_type
    except:
        await async_func()
        try:
            await sync_func()
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            print("sync_func() was CANCELLED (bad!)")

asyncio.run(test(excep_type=ValueError))
asyncio.run(test())
```

Hi there. I have a simple example

1. `test` is an async function which does nothing but raise a provided error type and then await both `async_func` and `sync_func` inside.
2. `sync_func` is a synchronous function made asynchronous with `sync_to_async` of the asgiref package.

Running this gives the following output:

```
Exception Type: <class 'ValueError'>
async_func() was CALLED (good!)
sync_func() was CALLED (good!)

Exception Type: <class 'asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError'>
async_func() was CALLED (good!)
sync_func() was CANCELLED (bad!)
```

In the first case, `ValueError` is raised and inside the exception clause, I can await `async_func` and `sync_func` like normal.

However in the second case, I have behaviour I wouldn't expect. I should be able to await `sync_func` like normal, but it instead raises `asyncio.CancelledError` as indicated by the printout.

In reality I haven't changed anything between the two calls, except changed the type of error which was originally raised and caught by the exception clause. However the type of raised error seems to have had an effect.

What this means real-world, is that I cannot use an asynchronous function wrapped by `sync_to_async` in any [clean-up activity of cancelled tasks](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task.cancel)

It seems this is caused by the `sync_to_async` decorator, as `async_func` runs fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That looks like an issue with the decorator. When I omit the decorator and replace `await sync_func()` with `await asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor(None, sync_func)`, your code runs just fine, so maybe you should avoid the decorator and just use the built-in asyncio functionality.

Comment: Thanks @user4815162342. This appears to be a bug with asgiref 3.3.1 which I've logged: https://github.com/django/asgiref/issues/247

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in `sync_to_async` introduced in asgiref 3.3.1.

https://github.com/django/asgiref/issues/247

This can be resolved using the built-in asyncio functionality or, if that is not possible, wrapping the failing coroutine in `create_task`.